# how to enable the Linker MAP file generation in Keil?

Tags: arm, keil

how to enable the generation of the Linker MAP file in Keil MDK-ARM
,in IAR Embedded Workbench i use the following steps
Options > Linker > List > check Generate linker map file.
I tried to use the same steps at Keil,MDK-ARM, but it didn't work, any help will be appreciated

Comment: How you did it in IAR is largely irrelevant, what you _tried_ in Keil would be more useful.  Tagging 8051 and ARM is probably not a good idea - the two tool-chains may differ, and if they don't then the tags are irrelevant in any case.  What is Keil-MD in any case?  There is a product Keil MDK-ARM, and the IDE is uVision - is either of thise what you meant?  Also what version?

Comment: yes i use Keil MDK-ARM and uVision 5.18a

Comment: "...it didn't work" is not the same as "I cannot find the setting..."; it rather suggests you tried something plausible and did not get the expected result.  If that is the case, you need to tell us what you did and what happened.  If in fact you did nothing, and simply cannot find the configuration setting, you need to say that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Project->Options for Target *target name*...->Listing Tab->Linker Listing check box**, select sub options as necessary.

Also useful:

In **Project->Options for Target *target name*...->Linker Tab->Misc Control**, add the following:

```
--info=summarystack --info=stack
```

Then all sorts of stack usage analysis will be included in the map file.

Comment: once i added them in the Misc Control  i get                                                       
 *** FATAL ERROR L224: DUPLICATE KEYWORD OR CONFLICTING CONTROL

Comment: So don't add them then!?  Did you look the error up in the documentation?  http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/bl51/bl51_l224.htm indicates that it is a BL51 error, suggesting that your toolchain is not ARM at all.  These are ARM linker options.